# In TFS Query view How to show Parent Id

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have a TFS query in Team Explorer that shows all Module Move Form (MMF), Review, Test Cases items that are assigned to me. I would like to have a column that shows the parent ids also. Example Reviews, Test Cases will have the 'ID for MMF' which is it's parent.

I looked in column options are did not see any columns that makes sense for this purpose. I am in VS2013

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt that a column is available for what you want. You can use a different type of query.

Select "Work items and direct links" and play around with the filters.

[image]

Comment: I was hoping for a flat list display...It is a matter of getting used too looking at